# Python problem with sending/receiving packets to local host address using socket and dpkt module

Tags: python, sockets, networking, send, packet

I'm trying to send an ICMP echo packet to my local host address and then return a response acknowledging that the packet was received. So far I have

```
def send_echo(socket, data, id, seq, dest):
    echo = dpkt.icmp.ICMP.Echo()
    echo.id = id
    echo.seq = seq
    echo.payload = bytes(data, 'utf-8')

   icmp = dpkt.icmp.ICMP()
   icmp.type = dpkt.icmp.ICMP_ECHO
   icmp.data = echo

   icmp_packed = icmp.pack()
   socket.sendto(icmp_packed, destination) #sending packet here
```

And then I wrote a function to receive this packet as follows:

```
def recv_response():
    mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP) 
    while True:
    try:
        received, addr = mySocket.recvfrom(1024)
        break
    except socket.error:
        test = 0
    return received
```

The loop gets stuck, so my guess is its not sending correctly but I'm not certain.

Main function:

```
def main():
    host_port = tuple(["127.0.0.1", 65432])
    send_echo(make_socket(50,50), "data", 0, 0, host_port)    
    recv_response()
```

So I get stuck in the loop in response but I'm not really sure if this is a sending problem or a receiving problem. Any help would be really appreciated.

**Edit**: Thanks Barmar, I used wireshark and successfully sent to 8.8.8.8. So the issue is with the receiving function.

Comment: Have you tried using a packet capture tool like WireShark to see if the packets are being sent?

Comment: Good idea, I'm downloading it right now. I'll keep you posted

Comment: Okay after using Wireshark and just sending to 8.8.8.8 it does seem to be sending properly. So my issue is with receiving packets.

Comment: According to the linked question you need to do `mySocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)`

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, let me know and I'll reopen.

Comment: I tried that but was getting an error. Then I realized the socket that sends the packet also has to be the same socket for receiving a response which fixed the issue, but thanks for the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255544/discussion-between-user19945252-and-barmar).

Comment: Hey Barmar, could you reopen this post? I still can't figure out how to receive the packet without sending the packet with the receiver socket. I tried using mySocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1) but I get the error "OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied" and I can't find much documentation on socket.IP_HDRINCL in general. There has to be a way to do this without including HDRINCL right?

Comment: You probably should specify that you're using Windows, the other answer was correct for UNix.

Comment: Hey Barmar, your comment gave me the idea to try this in linux, and it worked. sorry for wasting your time. Thanks though!